# What are some good WYSIWYG web editors

Tags: web-development

I need to take any URL on the web, open it in a WYSIWYG editor to make changes to it, and then save it as an HTML file.

What are the simplest solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the editors I like:

- [nicedit](http://nicedit.com/)
- [aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.com/) (A fast developing html5 editor)
- [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

You may also take a look at [wmd](http://wmd-editor.com/), a wysiwym editor (markdown editor).

Answer (score 0):

The best one I've ever used is [Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/).

From their website:

```
* WYSIWYG editing of pages, making web creation as easy as typing a letter with your word processor.
* Integrated file management via FTP. Simply login to your web site and navigate through your files, editing web pages on the fly, directly from your site.
* Reliable HTML code creation that will work with all of today's most popular browsers.
* Jump between WYSIWYG Editing Mode and HTML using tabs.
* Tabbed editing to make working on multiple pages a snap.
* Powerful support for forms, tables, and templates.
* The easiest-to-use, most powerful Web Authoring System available for Desktop Linux, Microsoft Windows and Apple Macintosh users.
```

The best part - its free and cross-platform.